# Deducing value of integral from another

Tags: complex-analysis

An exercise my teacher gave me is to calculate the path integral below, where $\gamma$ is the path from $0$ to $i$:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{z^2}{(1+z^3)^2}\ dz = \int_0^i \frac{z^2}{(1+z^3)^2}\ dz = \frac12\int_1^{1-i}\frac1{u^2}\ du= \frac{1-i}6$$

But the second part is what's giving me trouble; I'm supposed to use the calculations above to obtain the value of the following integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{t^2-t^8}{(1+t^6)^2}\ dt$$

I've tried many substitutions with no success, and I don't think any of the complex analysis theorems are of much help, since most of them are for closed path integrals. The fundamental theorem essentially tells me to find an antiderivative, but since I'm supposed to use the calculations from the first integral I don't think that's what I'm supposed to be doing.

Comment: The second integral can be done by substituting $t^3=u$ but that doesn’t give a form equivalent to the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the numerator and denominator of $\frac {z^{2}} {(1+z^{3})^{2}}$ by the complex conjugate of the denominator. You will see that the real part of this expression is exactly $ \frac {t^{2}-t^{8}} {(1+t^{6})^{2}}$. All you have to do now is to take real parts in the original equation.

Comment: How did I not think of this, thanks.